# How to fix WTForms validators

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm using `flask-wtform` and `wtform` validators, depending on the code below, some validators such as reCaptcha and EqualTo() are not working and the form submits without any validation. The rest of the flask app works correctly.

```
from flask import Flask
import os
from flask import render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm, RecaptchaField
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField, SubmitField, EmailField
from wtforms.validators import EqualTo, DataRequired

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(14).hex()
app.config['RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY'] = '6Lc1GDkfAAAAALAxoESfwgkO-sHdPpteq1JPW8Us'
app.config['RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY'] = '6Lc1GDkfAAAAAK2pfSfp_HT2VRNE0EkM0R5xpT3X'

class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField(validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = EmailField(validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField(validators=[DataRequired()])
    confirm = PasswordField(validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
    terms = BooleanField(label='سایت را می پذیرم', validators=[DataRequired()])
    recaptcha = RecaptchaField(validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField(label='ثبت نام')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/home', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    form = RegisterForm()
    return render_template('home.html', title='صفحه اصلی', form=form)





<section class="user-modal" id="user-modal">
        <form action="{{ url_for('home') }}" method="post">
            {{ form.csrf_token() }}
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.username }}<i class="fa-solid fa-user-large"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.email }}<i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.password }}<i class="fa-solid fa-lock"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.confirm }}<i class="fa-solid fa-lock"></i>
            </div>
            {{ form.recaptcha(style='margin-top:5px;') }}
            <div class="form-group terms-check">{{ form.terms }} <a href="#">شرایط و
                قوانین</a> {{ form.terms.label }}
            </div>
            {{ form.submit }}
        </form>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

So as to return any messages to user, form should be posted. Jinja2 gives an opportunity to pass for errors using macro codes and show theme all as ul>li together.

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
  <dt>{{ field.label }}
  <dd>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
  {% if field.errors %}
    <ul class=errors>
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <li>{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
  </dd>
{% endmacro %}
```